# What's the all fit header to show images?

Tags: php, image, header

```
header("Content-type:   image/gif");  
readfile($filename);
```

The above can only be used to show gif images.

Is there a header that can be used to show jpg/png/gif?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for all image types:

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);

header('Content-type: ' . $size['mime']);
readfile($filename);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
header("Content-type:   image/gif");
```

OR

```
header("Content-type:   image/jpeg");
```

OR

```
header("Content-type:   image/png");
```

Comment: Do I have other options than list them all?

Comment: **You can't use more than one.** It should match the content you're sending. If you're readfile'ing a GIF, it should be `image/gif`, a JPEG should be `image/jpeg`, and a PNG should be `image/png`.

Comment: Look <img src="" />,you dont have to specify its exact type.

Comment: That's because servers send the right content type so the browser knows what to do with it.

Comment: @new - This is called a MIME Type. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: It's also used to server http request,can I leave the content type to servers like <img src="" />?

Comment: The server will handle `<img>` tags because it's directly serving the image file. It won't handle a PHP script using `readfile()` because all the server knows is that it's a PHP script - it'll try to use `text/html` like all other PHP scripts. This is why you have to specify a `Content-type` header in such a script.

Comment: Then is there a way to let server directly serve the image file?

Comment: Yes - link to it directly instead of using a PHP script. Otherwise, you'll need to use one of the (easy) MIME type detection techniques described in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know or figure out what type of file it is, and send the proper type. There's no catch-all content type for images that'll work for GIF, PNG, and JPEG all at once.

[`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/finfo_file) will let you detect the type of an image (or any other file).